# Find the maximum degree of nodes in a tree

Tags: algorithm, collections, tree, children, iterable

first of all this is a homework question but I am not asking for the solution.
I have some ideas of where to start but I'd like some suggestions as well.

This is the question:
Write an algorithm max-degree(r) that receives as input the root r of a tree and it outputs the
maximum degree of the nodes in the tree.

I've been trying to use the children() method of the Tree ADT but this method returns an iterable collection. I don't even know what an iterable collection is or looks like so if anyone could give an example of children() being used on a tree object that would be very helpful. Additionally if you think I am taking the wrong approach to this problem by trying to utilize the children() method then please say so.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: java but I'm just writing a pseudo code for the question.
Like when I ask for an example of a iterable collection, it doesn't even have to be related to trees, I just have zero idea what it is in the first place so any example would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Not too familiar with the `children()` method in Java, but an iterable collection sounds like an array or a list. Try using a `foreach` on the object returned from `children()` which should allow you to access each individual object contained in the collection. Giving more than that would be answering your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check all children, and take max of [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29). You can navigate through the tree like in [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (here, [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) needs more memory). In pesudo-code it can looks like:

```
def max-degree(vertex root)
    solution = local_degree
    foreach(vertex x : root.children())
        solution = max(solution, max-degree(x))
    return solution
```

The special case is root of the tree, if you don't want to take into account his degree. But it's easy to solve.